# unexplained firebase real time database timeout getting data from client

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a weird issue where some of my users are getting timeouts when requesting their account information from the firebase realtime database (super small objects).

**Call to get user data**

```js
export const getUserData = (userId) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    onValue(
      ref(db, '/users/' + userId),
      (snapshot) => resolve(snapshot.val()),
      (err) => {
        console.error('err', err)
        reject(err)
      },
      { onlyOnce: true }
    )
  })
```

**User login hook:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    // onAuthStateChanged returns an unsubscribe method
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user)
      if (user) {
        const getUserDataTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
          // FAILS HERE FOR SOME USERS
          setLoading(false)
          setUserDataError(
            'User data request timeout, try refreshing the page or another browser, and please contact us at support@example.com.'
          )
           // 5s is irrelevant, after 1s it'll never complete
        }, 5000)
        getUserData(user.uid)
          .then((userData) => {
            setLoading(false)
            setUserData(userData)
            clearTimeout(getUserDataTimeout)
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error("couldn't get user data", err)
            setLoading(false)
            setUserDataError(err.message)
            clearTimeout(getUserDataTimeout)
          })
      } else {
        setLoading(false)
      }
    })
    return unsubscribe
  }, [])
```

When logging into that user's account, I have no issues. Their issue seems to go away when switching from latest Chrome to a different browser. I feel like it has something to do with web sockets being blocked by the network. I tried throttling the connection and it's still lightning fast. **Any advice on how to debug, or what could be causing it?**

Comment: Firebase has both real-time listeners and promise based APIs. Here you are mixing them together to build `getUserData` when you should use the Promise API itself (`get(ref)` instead of `onValue(ref)`) or use the listener API without Promises. Try refactoring that first and see if the issue persists.

Comment: @samthecodingman sadly it doesn't appear this solved the issue. Also, one of the users did get a more specific error of `Client is offline` but yet they logged info with firebase auth. Any thoughts?